# I have custom rom installed but I have a problem

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset

i installed a custom rom. now I want to open recovery but when I open it says "do you want to start factory reset (it will delete everything in phone)"

I don't want everything to be deleted I just want to start recovery. what can i do?

Comment: Is it an LG? And by custom ROM do you mean custom recovery?

Comment: Yes LG G2. And no I mean rom. Cloudy G2.

Comment: Ok. I figured since I also own LG. (Also Cloudy ROM too, but that is irrelevant in this case) You can go on to say *yes* and it'll boot into recovery.

Comment: are you sure? it says it will delete everything.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. You can ignore it completely. You used the **Power + Vol Down** combination when booting up I assume?

Comment: yes. i am normally familiar with recovery. but this phone is new and it is the first time I see this warning.

Comment: I will post a detailed answer.

Comment: it worked. i was actually scared to be honest. thank you. accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let me say this: **You can ignore it and go on since it will not actually delete anything (assuming you actually got a custom recovery installed)**

The combination of **Power + Volume Down** when LG logo appears during boot will bring the screen you mention. It gives you this warning because that is what the stock recovery is meant to do. However, with custom recovery being installed, it will just boot into recovery mode. This is because the process of factory resetting is done by recovery of the phone.

For example, if you start factory reset on Settings, it will just pass your command to recovery, and recovery will get the job done. That button combination is there just in case you can't boot into system at all. But by default, what that does is also the same, calling recovery to duty.

However, if you want to boot into Download/bootloader or recovery modes **without** using those methods, you can use the [Quick Boot app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot&hl=tr) to get the job done with ease.